how to restart improperly configured network
I accidentally tried to set a static IP without all the proper info filled in and didn't realize my mistake until after I restarted, at which point my ethernet no longer shows up at all, and I don't have WiFi, how do I restart my ethernet configuration offline?

You've provided no clue as to what Ubuntu product, or release you're using. Are you using a Ubuntu Core system? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? and what release of that product. We currently don't know what IP tools your machine use, as tools included vary on product/release.

I already figured out how to fix it, I just had to go to /etc/netplan and go into thr .yaml give for my network, then empty it and save, doing so reset all ethernet settings for my network

Well done for solving it, you've still not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; you could add those to your question, and then answer your own question in the answer section below (to help others with what you worked out).

Sorry, I'm still new to this, added version number for Ubuntu as shown in lsb_release -a, and I'm using the stock networking software that came with the install

Go to /etc/netplan, go into the .yaml file for the network configuration, and simply delete all text, save, and reboot, this worked for me on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS desktop after I was messing around with a few things hoping it would work
